# Setting custom ViewGroup/ composite View LayoutParameters inside its' constructor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-viewgroup

I'm extending the AppBarLayout to make my own version of it. My goal is it to set some LayoutParameters at runtime eg. the AppBar height.

I get an NPE, if I try setting any Paramteres, I guess beause the LayoutParameters are not yet created and set.

```
public MyAppBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ...

    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_my_app_bar, this, true);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = this.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = calculateExpandedHeight(selectedAspectRatio);
    this.setLayoutParams(params);

    ...
}
```

My current workaround is it to set the `LayoutParams` inside `onMeasure`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if(!hasSetHeight) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = this.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = mExpandedHeight;
        this.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set the LayoutParameters inside the constructor of a custom ViewGroup / composite View?

---

*layout_my_app_bar.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
</merge>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the NullPointerException you're getting is related to the LayoutParams being null because the View hasn't yet been laid out by the system. This gives you two options: you can either delay the param adjustment until the View has been laid out, or use the View's internal onMeasure (similar to how you're using) to tell it how to lay it out.

The former can be achieved with the OnGlobalLayoutListener from the ViewTreeOberserver:

```
public MyAppBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ...

    getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = this.getLayoutParams(); 
                // Set the params here

                removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(MyAppBar.this, this); // Remove the listener
            }
        });
    requestLayout();
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
        v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
    else v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
}
```

The latter, which may be (slightly) better since you're only applying what appears to be an aspect ratio, would be to use the onMeasure method and apply your transformation to the widthMeasureSpec within there. e.g.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int adjustedHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) / selectedAspectRatio

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, 
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(adjustedHeight, MeasureSpec.getMode(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)));
}
```

Keep in mind, that onMeasure isn't really taking the other MeasureSpec possibilities into account, and I'm making a huge assumption that you'll always know the width and want the height to adjust itself based on that. If you want to be a little more dynamic and account for other cases, [easy View measuring](https://www.buzzingandroid.com/2012/11/easy-measuring-of-custom-views-with-specific-aspect-ratio/) did a pretty good job explaining it. Just thought that may point you in the right direction.